# Logic App: Access for-each value in javascript step

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

In my Logic App I have a For-Each block that is iterating a json list. Inside the ForEach block, I have a JavaScript step in which I am trying to access the current object of the ForEach.

I have unsuccessfully tried:

```
workflowContext.actions["For_each"].body
```

> Error: InlineCodeOperationMissing. The inline code action
> 'JavaScriptCode' execution failed, with error 'The specified action
> 'For_each' is not in the provided workflowContext. Try including the
> action by adding it to explicitDependency.actions.

I also tried:

```
items('For_each').IsEmailSent
```

> InlineCodeScriptRuntimeFailure. The inline code action
> 'JavaScriptCode' execution failed, with error 'items is not defined'.

Answer (score 1):

> Error: InlineCodeOperationMissing. The inline code action
> 'JavaScriptCode' execution failed, with error 'The specified action 'For_each' is not in the provided workflowContext. Try including the
> action by adding it to explicitDependency.actions.

```
workflowContext.actions["For_each"].body
```

You can use this code.

```
workflowContext.actions.For_each.foreach
```

In my case action.for_each, in your case may be different steps you can go to code and see the structure.

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

More understanding read this article on how to use js in logic app [Franky's Notes](https://www.frankysnotes.com/2019/06/be-more-productive-by-using-inline-code.html) , [Cyber Engineer](https://www.cyber.engineer/azure-logic-apps-inline-js-convert-your-security-alert-severity/)